# subscribe not working inside angular service. Async issue?

Tags: angular

I have a form where the user enters a linux username and a date.
This info is used to create a new "delegation" entry in the database. Before I can call my REST API I need to translate this linux username into the primary key of the corresponding user record since the POST call expects this form data:

```
{ 
   'delegator': <user pk>, 
   'delegatee': <user pk>, 
   'expiration': <string for data YYYY-MM-DD>
}
```

So I have this service which gets the User from the database:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  getUsers(login: string)  {
    var url = environment.apiUrl + '/api/v1/users' + '/?autocomplete=1&login=' + login + '&type=employee';
    return this.http.get(url).map(res => <string[]>res.json());
  }
}
```

The service returns an array of strings of the format: `"login:user_id"`.  The `UserService` works fine as I will show below.

I call `getUsers()` in another service, `DelegationsService`. Here is the method defined in `DelegationsService` that makes the call to `getUsers()`:

```
export class DelegationsService {

  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  delegatees: string[];

  constructor(private http: Http, private userService: UserService) {}

  newDelegation (delegator: number, delegatee_login: string, expiration: string) {
    // translate the login of the delegatee_login into the userid for the delegatee.
    var resp = this.userService.getUsers(delegatee_login).subscribe((delegatees) => {
        this.delegatees = delegatees;
        console.log(this.delegatees);
        console.log( this.delegatees[0]);
        var delegatee_id = this.delegatees[0].split(':')[1];
        console.log( 'newDelegation line 42 : ' + delegatee_id );
    });
    if ( this.delegatees ) {
        console.log( 'newDelegation line 52 : ' + this.delegatees[0] );
    } else {
        console.log( 'newDelegation line 54 no delegatees returned' );
    }
    // make a fake body since we can't the the delegatee's user id.
    var body = { 'delegator': delegator.toString(), 'delegatee': '9999', 'expiration': expiration };
    console.log(body);
    return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/api/v1/delegation', body );
  }
```

Some things to note: I have debug code inside the `subscribe()` that demonstrates that I do get data from the `getUsers()` call.

When `newDelegations()` get invoked the console output in my browser is this:

```
newDelegation line 54 no delegatees returned
delegations-service.services.ts:57 {delegator: "975197", delegatee: "9999", expiration: "4000-04-04"}
delegations-service.services.ts:39 ["red:880922"]
delegations-service.services.ts:40 red:880922
delegations-service.services.ts:42 newDelegation line 42 : 880922
```

As we can see from the output above line 54 executes before line 39. Also the subscribe code block, which line 39 is in, has the data returned from the `getUsers()` call while line 54 does not.

What am I doing wrong?

Update:  I have rewritten the newDelegation method at per the suggestion made by iHazCode.

```
  newDelegation (delegator: number, delegatee_login: string, expiration: string) {
    this.userService.getUsers(delegatee_login).subscribe((delegatees) => {
        this.delegatees = delegatees;
        console.log(this.delegatees);
        console.log( this.delegatees[0]);
        var delegatee_id = this.delegatees[0].split(':')[1];
        console.log( 'newDelegation line 42 : ' + delegatee_id );
        var body = { 'delegator': delegator.toString(), 'delegatee': delegatee_id, 'expiration': expiration };
        console.log(body);
        return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/api/v1/delegation', body );
    });
  }
```

When the above code executes there is the post call to /api/v1/delegation does not appear in the network tab in my browser.  Just the get() request executed by `getUsers()`.

Update II.  Here is the code that calls `newDelegation()`.

```
export class DelegationDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  userid: number;
  login: string;
  @Input() delegation: Delegation;
  constructor(
    private delegationService: DelegationsService,

  ) {
    // faking this for now until authentication is working.
    this.userid = 975197;
    this.login = 'red2';
  }

...

  onSubmitNewDelegation(f: NgForm): void {
    console.log( 'Update delegation with id ' + f.value.delegator);
    this.delegationService.newDelegation(
                   f.value.delegator,f.value.delegatee,f.value.expiration);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Treat lines 37 thru 43 as a single statement, on a single line.  You'll see that you are calling the `getUsers`, and asking for `resp` to be subscribed to the result.  This is not a blocking operation, so line 44 and on are executed next.  `this.delegates` doesn't have a value yet on line 54, because the response from the server hasn't come back yet, and thus the `subscribe` hasn't fired yet.

Comment: Thanks Claies ... how do I correct the problem. How would I make this a blocking operation?

Comment: "How would I make this a blocking operation?" that's the wrong question.  Server requests through `http` are **always** non-blocking (Async).  What you really want to do is wait for the response, then make your `post` request in response.  which means, you don't want to subscribe to the result of the first call, and you can't return the response of the second directly.  you want to chain them so that it's something like (very rough pseudo) `return firstCall().then(secondCall(firstResponse).then(return secondResponse))`.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that out.  I still need to subscribe right? to pass the value of the delegatees[] to the second call.

Comment: Yeah ... I really don't understand what you are telling me.  what is "firstCall() and secondCall()"? Are they calls to my methods defined in my service or are they http.get() calls?

Comment: I'm not great at explaining this concept, which is why I tried to offer some ideas in comments.  Hopefully someone else might actually be able to provide some working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
    onSubmitNewDelegation(f: NgForm): void {
        console.log( 'Update delegation with id ' + f.value.delegator);
        this.delegationService.newDelegation(
                       f.value.delegator,f.value.delegatee,f.value.expiration).subscribe((result) => {
      console.log(result);
   });

}
```

Hope this helps.

P.S. I only had it send the result to the console so you can check that OR the network tab to ensure your POST is now occurring.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be to move everything from the if statement:

```
if (this.delegatees) etc...
```

Into your subscribe block for the (async) getUsers call.

Hope this helps

i.e.

```
var resp = this.userService.getUsers(delegatee_login).subscribe((delegatees) => {
        this.delegatees = delegatees;
        console.log(this.delegatees);
        console.log( this.delegatees[0]);
        var delegatee_id = this.delegatees[0].split(':')[1];
        console.log( 'newDelegation line 42 : ' + delegatee_id );
    if ( this.delegatees ) {
        console.log( 'newDelegation line 52 : ' + this.delegatees[0] );
    } else {
        console.log( 'newDelegation line 54 no delegatees returned' );
    }
    // make a fake body since we can't the the delegatee's user id.
    var body = { 'delegator': delegator.toString(), 'delegatee': '9999', 'expiration': expiration };
    console.log(body);
    return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/api/v1/delegation', body );
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried that but for some reason my rest api acts as it the post request was never made.

Comment: That would indicate another problem entirely then. A problem directly related to your service or the endpoint your hitting. Just to be clear, are you stating that in the network tab your seeing the POST does not succeed?

Comment: I do not even see my request in the network tab. The backend is fine as I can create delegations via curl. I'll post the new version of newDelegation.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as you seem to indicate the service is working fine in your question, but if you can't see the request completing (or even attempting) that seems to indicate there is a problem with the actual service call. Also I am curious, you mention a post, but the service in the snippet you included seems to be attempting a GET. Might be worthwhile dumbing the service down initially and just trying to perform the operation so we can view the response json then build things back up from there.

Comment: Apologies, if my previous comment was a bit scattered (I was just thinking out loud to some degree), I'm mostly trying to get the facts together. I am hoping I can emulate this scenario locally to see if I can provide some help. I will setup a dummy project in a moment if need be. Is it possible that your POST operation requires some of the header info you provided in your GET operation? Maybe just move this to the UserService as well.

Comment: There are two services involved here.  The UserService which works fine and the DelegationsService which is the one giving me so much trouble.  The DelegationsService.newDelegation() calls UserService.getUsers().

Comment: Was on a tablet earlier and apparently/completely missed that part when re-reviewing this. What does the caller code to your newDelegateService look like? I assume newDelegation method is returning Observable. Is it possible the subscription in the calling code is not getting wired up properly thus never initiating the http action?

Comment: In fact you could eliminate this possibility by simply subscribing to your POST method here. Please try that, check the network tab, and let us know.

Comment: Thanks iHazCode I have updated the post with the code that calls `newDelegation()`.

Comment: Did you try to subscribe to newDelegation? I suspect once you subscribe to that service call during your onSubmitNewDelegation method you will begin to see the POST at least attempt to occur in your network tab. Keep us posted.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions and advice. I finally got it working.  I moved the call to `getUsers()` to the component `DelegationDetailComponent.onSubmitNewDelegation()` and make the call to `newDelegation()` in the `.subscribe()` on `getUsers()`.